# Choosing the non-empty Monoid

Tags: haskell, monoids

I need a function which will choose a non-empty monoid. For a list this will mean the following behaviour:

```
> [1] `mor` []
[1]
> [1] `mor` [2]
[1]
> [] `mor` [2]
[2]
```

Now, I've actually implemented it but am wondering wether there exists some standard alternative, because it seems to be a kind of a common case. Unfortunately Hoogle doesn't help.

Here's my implementation:

```
mor :: (Eq a, Monoid a) => a -> a -> a
mor a b = if a /= mempty then a else b
```

Comment: A standard implementation won't exist because "monoidal things" have no notion of introspection (FWIW, lots of things with a Monoid instance won't support equality anyway).

Comment: @stephentetley Thanks! Why don't you post it as an answer with an explanation of what you imply under introspection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is really a long comment rather than an answer]

In my comment, when I said "monoidal things have no notion of introspection" - I meant that you can't perform analysis (pattern matching, equality, <, >, etc.) on monoids. This is obvious of course - the API of Monoids is only **unit** (mempty) and an operation **mappend** (more abstractly <>) that takes two monodial things and returns one. The definition of **mappend** for a type is free to use case analysis, but afterwards all you can do with monoidal things is use the Monoid API.

It's something of a folklore in the Haskell community to avoid inventing things, prefering instead to use objects from mathematics and computer science (including functional programming history). Combining Eq (which needs analysis of is arguments) and Monoid introduces a new class of things - monoids that support enough introspection to allow equality; and at this point there is a reasonable argument that an Eq-Monoid thing goes against the spirit of its Monoid superclass (Monoids are opaque). As this is both a new class of objects and potentially contentious - a standard implementation won't exist.

Answer (score 4):

If your lists contain at most one element, they're isomorphic to `Maybe`, and for that there's the "first non empty" monoid: `First` from `Data.Monoid`. It's a wrapper around `Maybe a` values, and `mappend` returns the first `Just` value:

```
import Data.Monoid
main = do
    print $ (First $ Just 'a') <> (First $ Just 'b')
    print $ (First $ Just 'a') <> (First Nothing)
    print $ (First Nothing)    <> (First $ Just 'b')
    print $ (First Nothing)    <> (First Nothing :: First Char)

==> Output:
First {getFirst = Just 'a'}
First {getFirst = Just 'a'}
First {getFirst = Just 'b'}
First {getFirst = Nothing}
```

Conversion `[a] -> Maybe a` is achieved using `Data.Maybe.listToMaybe`.

On a side note: this one does not constrain the typeclass of the wrapped type; in your question, you need an `Eq` instance to compare for equality with `mempty`. This comes at the cost of having the `Maybe` type, of course.

Comment: Sorry, but too specific. The question was about Monoids, not Lists and especially not one-item Lists.

Comment: What you're asking for is a monoid that requires `Eq` *in its instance definition* (as you can't define `mappend mempty b = ...`, because 'mempty' will simply be a pattern variable name). I highly doubt that exists, especially in the standard libraries.

Comment: I know about `Eq`, that's why it is declared in my question. The `mappend` solution would have been wrong, since in case of lists it would have concatenated them.

Answer (score 3):

First, your `mor` function looks rather suspicious because it requires a `Monoid` but never uses `mappend`, and so it is significantly more constrained than necessary.

```
mor :: (Eq a, Monoid a) => a -> a -> a
mor a b = if a /= mempty then a else b
```

You could accomplish the same thing with merely a [`Default`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default) constraint:

```
import Data.Default

mor :: (Eq a, Default a) => a -> a -> a
mor a b = if a /= def then a else b
```

and I think that any use of `Default` should *also* be viewed warily because, as I believe many Haskellers complain, it is a class without principles.

My second thought is that it seems that the data type you're *really* dealing with here is `Maybe (NonEmpty a)`, not `[a]`, and the `Monoid` you're actually talking about is `First`.

```
import Data.Monoid

morMaybe :: Maybe a -> Maybe a -> Maybe a
morMaybe x y = getFirst (First x <> First y)
```

And so then we could use that with lists, as in your example, under the `(nonEmpty, maybe [] toList)` isomorphism between `[a]` and `Maybe (NonEmpty a)`:

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty

morList :: [t] -> [t] -> [t]
morList x y = maybe [] toList (nonEmpty x `mor` nonEmpty y)
```

```
λ> mor'list [1] []
[1]

λ> mor'list [] [2]
[2]

λ> mor'list [1] [2]
[1]
```

(I'm sure that somebody more familiar with the *lens* library could provide a more impressive concise demonstration here, but I don't immediately know how.)

You *could* extend `Monoid` with a predicate to test whether an element is an identity.

```
class Monoid a => TestableMonoid a
  where
    isMempty :: a -> Bool

    morTestable :: a -> a -> a
    morTestable x y = if isMempty x then y else x
```

Not every monoid can have an instance of `TestableMonoid`, but plenty (including list) can.

```
instance TestableMonoid [a]
  where
    isMempty = null
```

We could even then write a newtype wrapper with a `Monoid`:

```
newtype Mor a = Mor { unMor :: a }

instance TestableMonoid a => Monoid (Mor a)
  where
    mempty = Mor mempty
    Mor x `mappend` Mor y = Mor (morTestable x y)
```

```
λ> unMor (Mor [1] <> Mor [])
[1]

λ> unMor (Mor [] <> Mor [2])
[2]

λ> unMor (Mor [1] <> Mor [2])
[1]
```

So that leaves open the question of whether the `TestableMonoid` class deserves to exist. It certainly seems like a more "algebraically legitimate" class than `Default`, at least, because we can give it a law that relates it to `Monoid`:

- `isEmpty x` iff `mappend x = id`

But I do question whether this actually has any common use cases. As I said earlier, the Monoid constraint is superfluous for your use case because you never `mappend`. So we should ask, then, can we envision a situation in which one might need *both* `mappend` and `isMempty`, and thus have a legitimate need for a `TestableMonoid` constraint? It's possible I'm being shortsighted here, but I can't envision a case.

I think this is because of something Stephen Tetley touched on when he said that this "goes against the spirit of its Monoid." Tilt your head at the type signature of `mappend` with a slightly different parenthesization:

```
mappend :: a -> (a -> a)
```

`mappend` is a mapping from members of a set `a` to functions `a -> a`. A monoid is a way of viewing *values* as *functions over those values*. The monoid is a view of the world of `a` *only* through the window of what these functions let us see. And functions are very limited in what they let us see. The only thing we ever do with them is apply them. We never ask anything else of a function (as Stephen said, we have no *introspection* into them). So although, yes, you can bolt anything you want onto a subclass, in this case the thing we're bolting on feels very different in character from the base class we are extending, and it feels unlikely that there would be much intersection between the use cases of functions and the use cases of things that have general equality or a predicate like `isMempty`.

So finally I want to come back around to the simple and precise way to write this: Write code at the value level and stop worrying classes. You don't need `Monoid` and you don't need `Eq`, all you need is an additional argument:

```
morSimple :: (t -> Bool) -- ^ Determine whether a value should be discarded
          -> t -> t -> t
morSimple f x y = if f x then y else x
```

```
λ> morSimple null [1] []
[1]

λ> morSimple null [1] [2]
[1]

λ> morSimple null [] [2]
[2]
```